# Google Drive API: Invalid Images being downloaded

Tags: image, lua, download, google-drive-api, coronasdk

I''ve written an app in lua using the Corona SDK, I'm trying to download some images from a google drive folder.

I've used the OAth playground to authroize the scopes I need and I've obtained a refresh token and have a method to obtain a new access token when necessary. This is how I download the images:

```
network.download(
                   "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="..decodedResponse.files[index].id,
                    "GET",
                    networkListener,
                    params,
                    decodedResponse.files[index].name,
                    system.DocumentsDirectory
                )
```

where `decodedResponse` refers to the json obtained that lists all the files in the specified folder. This was working fine a few days ago but now whenever I try it, the image downloaded is invalid and corrupt. I even tried using a new folder in the drive.

I've tried other links such like

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID_HERE?alt=media`

and some others I've seen online but these give me a

`code 403 
"Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."`

error. I read somewhere that specifying scope could fix the code 403 error but I'm not sure where exactly to specify this.

I'd appreciate the help, thanks!

Edit: I took a look at one of the images with a text editor, the result was some html that look to be code for a google auth page, some of it is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=300, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <meta name="description" content="Google Drive is a free way to keep your files backed up and easy to reach from any phone, tablet, or computer. Start with 15GB of Google storage – free.">
  <meta name="google-site-verification" content="LrdTUW9psUAMbh4Ia074-BPEVmcpBxF6Gwf0MSgQXZs">
  <title>Meet Google Drive – One place for all your files</title>
  <style>
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTYnF5uFdDttMLvmWuJdhhgs.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(//fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3aCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf) format('truetype');
}
  </style>
  <style>
  h1, h2 {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
  from {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
  opacity: 1;
  }
  }
  </style>
<style>
  html, body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #404040;
  direction: ltr;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  }
  button,
  input[type=button],
  input[type=submit] {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  }
  a,
  a:hover,
  a:visited {
  color: #427fed;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
  h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #262626;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  }
  h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #262626;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  input[type=email],
  input[type=number],
  input[type=password],
  input[type=tel],
  input[type=text],
  input[type=url] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
  border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #404040;
  }
  input[type=email]:hover,
  input[type=number]:hover,
  input[type=password]:hover,
  input[type=tel]:hover,
  input[type=text]:hover,
  input[type=url]:hover {
  border: 1px solid #b9b9b9;
  border-top: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  input[type=email]:focus,
  input[type=number]:focus,
  input[type=password]:focus,
  input[type=tel]:focus,
  input[type=text]:focus,
  input[type=url]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #4d90fe;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
  input[type=checkbox],
  input[type=radio] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:active,
  input[type=radio]:active {
  background: #ebebeb;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:hover {
  border-color: #c6c6c6;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }
  input[type=radio] {
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked,
  input[type=radio]:checked {
  background: #fff;
  }
  input[type=radio]:checked::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  background: #666;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked::after {
  content: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/ui/v1/menu/checkmark.png);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
  left: -5px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: #4d90fe;
  }
  .stacked-label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: .5em 0;
  }
  .hidden-label {
  position: absolute !important;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  }
  input[type=checkbox].form-error,
  input[type=email].form-error,
  input[type=number].form-error,
  input[type=password].form-error,
  input[type=text].form-error,
  input[type=tel].form-error,
  input[type=url].form-error {
  border: 1px solid #dd4b39;
  }
  .error-msg {
  margin: .5em 0;
  display: block;
  color: #dd4b39;
  line-height: 17px;
  }
  .help-link {
  background: #dd4b39;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-border-radius: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  }
  .help-link:visited {
  color: #fff;
  }
  .help-link:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #c03523;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  .help-link:active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #ae2817;
  }
  .wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  }
  .content {
  padding: 0 44px;
  }
  .main {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  /* For modern browsers */
  .clearfix:before,
  .clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  }
  .clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  }
  /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
  .clearfix {
  zoom:1;
  }
  .google-header-bar {
  height: 71px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .header .logo {
  background-image: url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/logo_1x.png);
  background-size: 116px 38px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 17px 0 0;
  float: left;
  height: 38px;
  width: 116px;
  }
```

I can't post the entire thing cause it exceeds the body character limit

Comment: You might want to take a look at your "corrupt" downloaded images with a text editor.  They may actually contain readable error messages.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot really? I'll take a look, thanks!

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it doesn't contain any readable error message but it seems to be html downloaded instead of an image, I'm not sure why, everything was working fine a few days ago

Comment: It sounds as if Google has changed the way their service works.  I don't have any further suggestions, but, on the bright side, you've learned a new troubleshooting tactic. :)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yeah, I managed to get it to work though and thanks for the new new tactic, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by using a different url and adding this:

```
local params = {}
params.progress = true
params.headers = headers
```

This was the URL I used:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID_HERE?alt=media